# Text File To Csv File Problam (+) is Not Show

Tags: csv, ms-office, export-to-csv, vcf-vcard

I have a problem with CSV file.
I have a text Contacts file 
like 
that
+923334897142
+923334897143
+923334897144
+923334897145
+923334897146
+923334897147
+923334897148
when 
I am converting this text file in to CSV file, then CSV file Show my numbers 
without + 
example
 
923334897142
923334897143
923334897144
923334897145
923334897146
923334897147
923334897148

I want my all numbers with + in to csv file, I am using total CSV converter. or 
if any program that convert my Text file direct in to Vcf, Vcard file, then 
inform me. (Window 7 - office 2007)

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of what the line should look like:
"=""+923334897142"""

See this as a reference:
https://superuser.com/questions/318420/formatting-a-comma-delimited-csv-to-force-excel-to-interpret-value-as-a-string

Comment: Thanks John Kane For Give your important time to my Problem,  i have not solve my problem, My Q. is 
 

Hi Every one i have a problem with CSV file.
i am try a text Contacts file like that
+923334897142
+923334897143
+923334897144
+923334897145
+923334897146
+923334897147
+923334897148
when i am convert this text file in to CSV file, Then CSV file Show my numbers without + example
 
923334897142
923334897143
923334897144
923334897145
923334897146
923334897147
923334897148
i want my all numbers with + in to csv file,

Comment: If you change the text to look like my example, it'll appear in Excel the way you want.

Comment: Thank you so much for reply. i am very thankful if you give me a example video tutorial on my work, how to do. thanks my email address is usmanaliofficial@gmail.com

Comment: i am not now how to do this

Comment: This is the instructions...I would appreciate it https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers